# SQL Server stored procedure for removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

To start I am not very proficient with SQL scripting, but I have been given a task and I would appreciate some guidance/help with creating this procedure, thank you in advance.

What needs to be done is, get duplicates for each customer from table 1 (table1 has id and id3)

I assume this part should be doable with

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM table1 t2 
              WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t2.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY Id, Name
```

or

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT [Name]
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY t1. [Name]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
ORDER BY t1.Customer, t1.Name
```

After that the IDs of those duplicates have to be cross referenced with table2 and get the corresponding IDs (Id2) from table2.

I assume that this part should be done by some kind of array to store the IDs or temporary table

The duplicates from table1, whose names correspond with a predetermined list and have an id3 that is not NULL should be deleted

Something like

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE Name IN ('name1', 'name2'.......)
  AND id3 IS NOT NULL
```

Along with all of the other duplicates for each customer (leave only the first entry for each duplicate).

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Comment: Can't 2 different customers have the same name? Definitely need some sample data.

Comment: Yes 2 customers can have the same name in the tables compared to each other, but they should not have the same name in their entries more than once.

John             Daydream
John             Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Amber            Fly_co
Amber            Fly_co
Jackie           Fly_co
Jackie           Fly_co

Comment: Here is an example for table1

       Customer        |   id1                 id3
---------------------------
          John         |    Daydream   |  NULL 
          John         |    Daydream   |  5fasgw323543#2
          Peter        |    Daydream   |  NULL
          Peter        |    Daydream   |  334gdfdshsdffds
          Peter        |    Daydream   |  fsfa4334gdfgdfg
          Amber        |    Fly_co     |  NULL
          Amber        |    Fly_co     |  dsasdre4343hj4
          Jackie       |    Fly_co     |  NULL
          Jackie       |    Fly_co     |  ewr4jgos4343hf

Answer (score 0):

Until the question can be clarified, I'd start by using a **[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
      , rn = row_number() over (
          partition by name 
          order by isnull(id,2147483647), isnull(id3,0)
              )
    from table1 t1
    --/*
    where exists (
      select 1 
        from table1 t2 
        where t1.name = t2.name 
          and t2.id is null
        )
    --*/
)

--/*
select * 
  from cte o
  where exists (
    select 1 
      from cte i 
      where i.name=o.name 
        and i.rn>1
        );
  --*/

  --delete from cte where rn>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a common table expression to delete any duplicate records. This will number every duplicate which will let you delete all but the first one. You should be able to modify this code for your needs. I would test it by selecting from the *CTE* first, before deleting anything.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) as row_num
    FROM table1
    where col4 = 'SOMETHING' //optional
)

--select * from CTE
--select * from CTE where row_num > 1

delete from CTE where row_num > 1
```